# Como Listar fotos adicionadas na view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Tenho o seguinte código na minha View que pega o caminho da foto, e salva no banco.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "PessoaFoto", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.Hidden("idPessoa", Request.QueryString["idPessoa"])
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" />

    }
```

como faço pra listar essas fotos na View a medida que vou adicionando?

O que eu quero é que a medida que eu for adicionando as fotos na minha view elas apareçam para q eu possa visualiza-las..

Por exemplo:[image: a visualização da foto aparecer]

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Sua pergunta está um pouco ampla. Poderia postar o código que está utilizando e explicar um pouco mais o que deseja. Aproveitando, veja [ask] e faça um [tour], para aprender um pouco mais sobre o funcionamento do site para assim aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem várias formas de fazer o que deseja. A mais simples é ter um elemento `img` em seu código, e ao selecionar a imagem (neste exemplo eu estou utilizando o `.change()`) você adiciona a imagem.

Um exemplo básico seria esse:

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#File").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <input type='file' id="File" />
  <img id="preview" src="#" />
</form>
```

[Esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4459379/4843158) possui várias formas de fazer isso, inclusive a que eu demonstrei acima.

Comment: Valeu, deu certo.